# Can you run multiple discord bots from discord bot maker on ONE dyno?

Tags: bots, discord

I was wondering if I could run MULTIPLE discord bots on ONE heroku dyno. Because I'm not paying $7 per discord bot hosted. If this is the case, where 1 dyno can only run 1 bot, im using glitch.com

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the same package multiple times and make few clients that are differently named. But it would be pretty hard to manage. I have never tested it out on discord.js npm package.